# How to copy a gradle dependency jar from gradle's cache?

Tags: gradle, mysql-connector

I'm developing a Java application that connects to a MySQL database using the 'mysql:mysql-connector-java' dependency in *build.gradle*. I want to connect to the same database through Eclipse Data Source Explorer using as driver the jar that is downloaded in the gradle's cache due to the aforementioned dependency.

I tried configuring the driver with the cached jar (mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar), but its location and name changes in every new version, so I would prefer to have it copied to a fixed destination.

I expect only this jar to be copied with a fixed filename into a *lib* folder by gradle itself, if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't declare the dependency with the *implementation* configuration but with a custom one, which I named *toCopy* and then I added a task in order to copy only the specific jar in a fixed location:

```
configurations {
    toCopy
    implementation {
        extendsFrom toCopy
    }
}

dependencies {
    toCopy 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
}

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.toCopy
    into 'lib'
    rename '(.*)', 'mysql-connector-java.jar'
}
```

Then I can call `gradle copyToLib` and the jar is being copied to the *lib* folder.